# Reading Cell Value in Excel using Libxlsxwriter?

Tags: libxlsxwriter

I want to read the result of the cell value into a variable. The cell which was used as an array formula to calculate the XIRR value. can I do this using libxlsxwriter?

Answer (score 1):

> can I do this using libxlsxwriter?

No. Libxlsxwriter cannot be used to read an xlsx file and it also doesn’t calculate the result of a formula; it just writes a default value of 0.

Comment: I know, you are the author of libxlsxwriter library. If you add the read feature within the library it helps a lot.

Comment: That won't happen, unfortunately. It is just too much work.